# Multiple values change when changing a single value in a nested list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, nested-lists

I noticed a weird behavior when I am changing a value in a nested list `grid` which is initialized as such `grid = [[0]*10]*10`.

```
grid = [[0]*10]*10

grid[0][0] = 1

for l in grid:
    print l
```

Output:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

When I initialised `grid` as `grid = [[0]*10 for x in range(10)]`.
It worked as expected.

```
grid = [[0]*10 for x in range(10)]

grid[0][0] = 1

for l in grid:
    print l
```

Output:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Does anyone know why this happened?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create `grid = [[0]*10]*10`, you are actually creating an array of references to *the same object* (a list of [0]s). So when you change the object via one reference, this changes all entries in the list.

This is a very common Python 'gotcha' for beginners.

Comment: yes @Andrew is correct.

# Explanation
grid = [[0]*10]*10  #  here initiated a list and assigned to grid

grid = [[0]*10 for x in range(10)]  # here constructing a list and assigning to grid